# Unresolved sincos during build of LAPACK

Tags: android-ndk, fortran, lapack, blas

Following the instructions [here](http://specificimpulses.blogspot.com/2011/10/android-fortran-step-by-step-part-2.html) I have built a Fortran enabled NDK toolchain (OSX, NDK-7b) with the goal of building LAPACK/BLAS.

Using android-cmake with the 3.4.0 net lib source it seems that I'm nearly successful. However, the BLAS build fails when linking one of the tests (with an error stating unresolved `sincos` and `sincosf`).  A little searching reveals that these functions are not available in legacy Android versions. I'm wondering what is the best way to resolve these functions?

Below is and example of a linking error:

> cd /Users/marc/software/lapack-3.4.0/Android/BLAS/TESTING && /opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/xblat2c.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
>   /opt/local/share/java/android-ndk-macosx/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7.0/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gfortran   -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined  -lstdc++ -lsupc++  CMakeFiles/xblat2c.dir/cblat2.f.o  -o ../../bin/xblat2c -rdynamic -L/Users/marc/software/lapack-3.4.0/Android/systemlibs/armeabi-v7a -L/opt/local/share/java/android-ndk-macosx/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7.0/prebuilt/darwin-x86/user/libs/armeabi-v7a ../../lib/libblas.a -lm -Wl,-rpath,/Users/marc/software/lapack-3.4.0/Android/systemlibs/armeabi-v7a:/opt/local/share/java/android-ndk-macosx/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.7.0/prebuilt/darwin-x86/user/libs/armeabi-v7a 
>   /opt/local/share/java/android-ndk-macosx/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-
>
> 4.7.0/prebuilt/darwin-x86/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.0/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libgfortran.a(c99_functions.o): In function `cexpf':
>   /opt/local/share/java/android-ndk-macosx/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.7.0/libgfortran/intrinsics/c99_functions.c:910: undefined reference to`sincosf'

Comment: Can you format your linking error a bit, or is it supposed to be one long line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC needs to know at compile time whether `sincos` is available or not. It does so based on the target. In case of the target triplet `arm-linux-androideabi`, it looks at `gcc/config/linux.h` and finds there:

```
/* Whether we have sincos that follows the GNU extension.  */
#undef TARGET_HAS_SINCOS
#define TARGET_HAS_SINCOS (OPTION_GLIBC || OPTION_BIONIC)
```

The reason for the inclusion of Bionic is that Android 2.3 added support for `sincosf`/`sincos`/`sincosl` [1]. Thus, you can either update Bionic or you patch GCC to assume that no `sincos` is available; cf. also [2].

[1] http://source-android.frandroid.com/bionic/libc/docs/CHANGES.TXT

[2] https://bugs.launchpad.net/linaro-android/+bug/908125

Comment: Thanks. So, my toolchain was built with OPTION_BIONIC therefore thinking sincos is available?  But libm is from pre Android 2.3, so it really isn't available?